After the conversion, Python removes static and noise from the audio file. --Little endian and Big endian
some sound files of “.aus” and “.sty” Org Musical instrument sound file with Python have more than one endian. The problem is that it should be able to detect and analyze both endian and convert the endian in the audio file to a single endian without distorting the sound and then convert it to “.wav”. However, when we convert the big endian to little endian, we get sizzle and noise bursts. I'm looking for a fix that can detect both endian and only do little endian and still preserve the quality of the sound. I'm new to Python, so my code knowledge is a bit limited. How can I solve this problem?
My codes:
def detect_endian(self, segment):
    little_endian_samples = [struct.unpack('<h', segment[i:i+2])[0] for i in range(0, len(segment), 2)]
    big_endian_samples = [struct.unpack('>h', segment[i:i+2])[0] for i in range(0, len(segment), 2)]

    sum_little_endian = sum(abs(sample) for sample in little_endian_samples)
    sum_big_endian = sum(abs(sample) for sample in big_endian_samples)

    return 'little' if sum_little_endian < sum_big_endian else 'big'

def convert_segment_to_little_endian(self, segment, endian):
    if endian == 'little':
        return segment

    converted_segment = bytearray()
    for i in range(0, len(segment), 2):
        sample = struct.unpack('>h', segment[i:i+2])[0]
        converted_segment.extend(struct.pack('<h', sample))
    return converted_segment

“

What is the segment? Can you explain why you are reading it to get endianess? In particular, why endianess is determined by a sort of majority vote?

A segment in this context refers to a small portion of the audio file's data. It is a chunk of bytes that represents a part of the sound wave in the file. For example, if an audio file is 1 minute long, you might process it in 1-second segments.  The endianess of an audio file refers to the byte order used to represent the audio samples. Audio samples are typically stored as 16-bit (2 bytes) integers, and the endianess determines the order in which these bytes are read.

Determining the endianess by a majority vote is a method used to analyze the most common byte order in the segments of the audio file. By examining multiple segments, we can infer the correct endianess based on the byte order that produces the most coherent (least distorted) audio data.

Why not read it from the header, RIFF (little endian) vs RIFX (big endian)? Another thing: to my knowledge it is not possible to infer endianess by reading bytes alone. Last but not least: review your previous questions and accept answers (or provide feedback).
